# If $X_1, \dots , X_n$ are discrete random variables and $h: \Bbb{R}^n \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$, show that $h(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ is also discrete RV.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \Bbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be discrete random variables in $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \Bbb{P})$. Furthermore, let $h: \Bbb{R}^n \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be an $\mathcal{F}$-measurable function. I need to show that the function $Z: \Omega \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ defined by $Z(\omega):= h(X_1(\omega), \dots, X_n(\omega))$ is also a discrete random variable in $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \Bbb{P})$. So we have to find a countable set $S_Z \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ such that $\Bbb{P}(Z \in S_Z) = 1$.

Since each $X_i$ is discrete, we know that there must exist a countable set $S_i \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ such that $\Bbb{P}(X_i \in S_i) = 1$ for each $i \in \{1, \dots , n\}$. In principle, these sets $S_i$ are the ones that must be used to find the candidate $S_Z$, but I'm not sure on how to procede now. Could $S_Z$ be, say, $h(S_1 \times \cdots \times S_n)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your guess for $S_Z$ is correct. Are you having trouble proving it?

Comment: This is just composition. Recall that random variables are measurable functions.

Comment: @JoeShmo, the question is not about measurability, but about being discrete.

Comment: @zhoraster, you misunderstood my comment. measurable functions are functions.

Comment: @Karl Unfortunately, yes. Here's the issue I've ran into: suppose, say, $s \in S_1$ and $X_1(w) = s$ for some $w \in \Omega$. I don't know which are the values of $X_2, \dots, X_n$ in this particular $\omega$; consequently, I cannot know if $Z(\omega) \in S_Z$, since it may be the case that $X_2(\omega)$ is not in $S_2$, for example. That ends up screwing up the calculation of $\Bbb{P}(Z \in S_Z)$ (i.e. I don't know if it ends up equal to 1).

Comment: Hmm, do you have the intuition for why the statement is true? Roughly: a discrete RV has a countable set of "possible values"; if there are only countably many possible inputs to the function $h$, there can be only countably many possible outputs. Try following this idea - think about the complement of $S_Z$ and try to show that it's a finite union of null sets.